# ido mode keeps suggesting mismatching buffer name

Tags: completion, ido

Here is the relevant part of my configuration file:

```
(require 'ido)
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
(setq ido-everywhere t)
(setq ido-auto-merge-work-directories-length -1)
(ido-mode 1)
```

The problem is, I want to create a new buffer named `*work*`, but ido mode keeps "suggesting" me to switch a buffer named `*code-concersion-work*`, despite their mismatching names. To make things more confusing, the suggested buffer doesn't even exist in the output of `ibuffer`.

[image]

How can I create a new `*work*` buffer?

Comment: `C-j` should create a buffer with the name you want and ignore the suggestions.

Comment: Please post a single question. I don't think your main question here has to do with Ibuffer. It seems to be a question about the buffer-name completion offered by Ido. But as @DoMiNeLa10 has commented, you can just type `*work* RET`, instead of completing.